# angularjs drag and drop html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a live HTML editor with AngularJS, where user can drag and drop some DOM elements to a container and it will render the final HTML page, for example, there is a button (or whatever) that says "Drag me to create an input", then user will drag that item into the container and an input field will be rendered...

I've been trying ngDraggable module but isn't what I needed...

I think a way is to hold the HTML code into some `$scope` variable, and when the user drops the button into the container, `$scope.input` which contains `<input type="text" placeholder="Something"/>` will be rendered inside container...

My final step is to enable inline edit to thoose HTML elements generated, in order to let the user create some content agains that final template.

When the user finish, the whole HTML code will be saved somewhere or downloaded...

I don't need something complex, just a few predefined elements that can be dropped...

I hope I've explained it correctly.

There is some example found at http://nboychev.com/tests/angular/Drag%20Drop%20iFrame%20using%20Angular%20JS%20Directive.html that does exactly what I want (see source), BUT:

It's using jQueryUI (Which I don't want to use, but if its needed then I will)

It isn't working on my project. I must say that I'm using RequireJS, but everything works on my angular app but the directives mentioned on the link above. Draggable is not working, I do not have any errors and I've checked that the code is being executed, doing some console.log() stuff, but still not working...

But it contains what I want, draggable stuff with HTML injected that renders content on an iframe (or a div, or whatever) and that new content is also droppable, to insert more stuff inside that code. Give it a try, and guide me a little. Thanks

Comment: To clarify: are you talking about having a "toolbox" of items that can be dragged into your container to create new elements in the container?

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I want. But, in order to save space and be more user friendly, I don't want the toolbox elements to be rendered as they are, for example, a `navbar` from `Bootstrap3`, just a button that says "Navbar" and when It is dropped, a navbar is rendered.

Comment: Need to work on similar requirement... were you able to find a way out?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you try using something as [jui](https://github.com/wlepinski/angularjs-jqueryui)

On the other hand you can try implementing your own directive:

```
 <br>
  <h4>Drop Area</h4>
  <div droppable jui-options="{addClasses: false}" class="drop-area"></div>

  <div class="read-out">
    <span class="text-info"><strong>Draggable ID</strong></span>: {{obj.id}}<br><br>
    <span class="text-info"><strong>Content</strong></span>: <span ng-bind-html="obj.content"></span><br><br>
    <span class="text-info"><strong>Actual Content</strong></span>: {{obj.content}}<br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/m-e-conroy/pen/jCdhu

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a fun project.

This is a simple link function using JqueryUI and Angular. You'll need an HTML element in scope with class "draggable". Use [destroy()](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-destroy) when finished.

Adding HTML to the DOM from the scope, check out this solution by Josh David Miller: http://jsfiddle.net/paulocoelho/fBjbP/2/

Or for simple HTML elements for visual display only you could try using ngBindHtml, ngRepeat and ngSanitize. Then adding / removing HTML elements to and from an array should display them in a container.

```
link: function($scope, $elem, $attr){

  $elem.find(".draggable").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui){
      $(ui.item).addClass("shadow");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui){
      $(ui.item).removeClass("shadow");
      // DO SOME ANGULAR STUFF HERE
    }
  });
}
```